# Show Pop Up Message box window using Windows task scheduler in c#

Tags: c#

I have created a scheduled task on my system and I want it to show an error message in a Message Box.

I have tried below options but they're not working.

- `/Create /RU SYSTEM /SC /ST /TN /TR /IT`
- `MessageBox.Show` option with `MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification`

Comment: MessageBoxes are shown, not THROWN. Also, what do you want to do!?

Comment: Is `MessageBox.Show option with MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification` supposed to be your code?  If so this is not valid C#.  If not can you please post your code.  Also, how is it "not working"?

Comment: Usually a task would just write to a system log somewhere. Popping up a MessageBox out of thin air from some task running in the background is going to confuse users...

Comment: The requirement is to show message box when the scheduled task is unable to establish connection with the SQL Server.

Comment: No idea why this was migrated here.